# Defining other resources clobbers theme in WPF

Tags: wpf, styles

I am building some WPF pages in a win forms application.  I wish to use WPF Themes for my application. Not having an `App.xaml` (because the project is a win forms project with a WPF `ElementHost` to show the WPF forms) I added my theme resource dictionary in my form like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/ExpressionDark.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

This works for all controls on this form plus some of the other WPF user controls, but there are some user controls where the theme is not functioning. I have tracked down that the affected controls that define their own resources like this:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 2 5 2" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

It doesn't seem to matter where the resources are located or what is in the resource. Anything in the resource that is not keyed blocks the theme for everything that style targets. I even tried to out-smart it by finding the resource in the dictionary:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

And modifying my style to look like this:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxTemplate}" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 2 5 2" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

But that caused my combo boxes to disappear completely!

Is there any way to add resources that blanket target controls and not throw off the theme?

Comment: @Dave Clemmer, why would you edit the tags from something more specific `wpf-styles` to something less specific `styles`? That seems to me to be a really bad idea!

Comment: I retagged as styles so that more people can find this post, as virtually nothing will come up under wpf-styles.  I've been told that wpf- tags are being discouraged.  In any case, the tag descriptions should reflect this.

Comment: Interesting.  The problem with that is when people choose tags to follow you can't say `wpf` AND `styles` so you might get web, android, delphi, etc. But I guess I don't get to make the rules.

Comment: You can certainly search with multiple tags by typing `[wpf][styles]`, but it would be nice to be able to add more tags to your search in the UI without having to type them in. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the `BasedOn` property of the `Style` to the old implicit `Style`:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" 
           TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 2 5 2" />
    </Style>

</Grid.Resources>
```

**edit**

So, if you don't want to use the resource key on all of your ComboBox's, you have to take it one step further. I don't know why WPF / WinForms interop handles implicit styles so poorly, but even if you add an implicit style to the resources here, and set `BasedOn="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"`, you will still lose your template.

However, if you move the resources to the UserControl, you can then do the implicit style properly:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/ExpressionDark.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" 
               TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 2 5 2" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" 
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" />
    </Grid.Resources>
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that! :)

Comment: I did not get the style on the ComboBoxes (except for the Margin property).  I tried it with and without the resource key and both times it had the same result. Besides, I didn't want to put a Style tag on each combo box.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to use the implicit styles. Also, I just noticed in the question that on the offending controls you weren't merging in the external resource. I made sure to show in the updated answser that the merged resources are still required.